# web application deployment on JBoss

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications, netbeans-7, jboss5.x

I am new to Java EE concepts and the JBoss server. I have developed a simple Enterprise application. I started the server using a command prompt but the moment I tried to deploy it from Netbeans the JBoss Application Server start failed:

`HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use` is displayed on the output.

So how can I deploy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE will start the JBoss server but it seems you already started from console therefore port is in use. Shut down it from console and try it only from your IDE. IDE will start it by itself.

Comment: even I have tried to start from IDE ,the same message appears.

Comment: Clearly, your port 8080 is in use. Have you started any other server like tomcat? Please be sure that you shutdown all servers you started from console jboss, tomcat, glashfish etc. I assume you use Windows, you can check which process listens 8080 port by 'netstat -aon -p tcp'

Comment: found that reason as the JBoss server is running on port 8080 . Such that when I start again JBoss server again it makes that message. Once I go ahead and run the application it works well. Thank you Alper.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the application that use port 8080 by tapping the netstat on command prompt. Then kill the application by his PID : `**taskkill /PID number that represent the PID**` of the application. Or download TCP viewer to see the application that uses the port 8080. then end the process, then try to start your JBoss